# Store DataSet on Sharepoint: ReadXml fails while WriteXml works flawlessly

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, dataset

I have a simple win forms application which loads/saves datasets into XML files. As long as I'm working with file shares or the local file system all is good.

Using the standard open file/save file dialog on my Windows 8 box, allows me to browse to my sharepoint using

https:// some sharepoint host

and I can browse the sharepoint sites/projects and document libraries.

Here's the weird part (because I didn't expect it to work like this at all):
When I use the file save dialog to browse to a sharepoint document library, the path is converted into something like '\sharepointhost@SSL\somepath\somemorepath\somefile.xml'

Passing the above path to the DataSet WriteXml method works fine and the file is correctly written to the document library.

Passing the very same path to the DataSet ReadXml method doesn't work and I get an exception:
"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

What am I missing here. I mean, I expected both methods to use the same code to parse/resolve the path.

Comment: Are you using the same procedure around the call in both cases? What happens if you try to open a filestream first and then pass the stream to `ReadXml`?

Comment: Maybe the stored file is not checked in yet?

Comment: The file is checked in and can be downloaded correctly. The weird thing is that the string passed as path is exactly the same in both methods (ReadXml and WriteXml) but ReadXml is complaining that it cannot parse the hostname in the URI. I'm wondering how the WriteXml is able to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to check if your code works on non-secured (http) connection? Maybe this error applies to your scenario?

[XmlReader for webdav path with ssl](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614602/xmlreader-throws-uri-exception-for-webdav-path-with-ssl) (ReadXml internally uses XmlReader).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have to add prefix ftp://" or "http://" in your READXML